# SSH Key Forwarding

Tags: macos, docker, ssh-keys

I am trying to clone a private github repository when building a docker image. I have docker 18.09.2 installed and according to [`Build secrets and SSH forwarding in Docker 18.09`](https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/build-secrets-and-ssh-forwarding-in-docker-18-09-ae8161d066#586a) and [`Using SSH to access private data in builds`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds), I should be able to use the forwarded ssh key by setting up my Dockerfile like this:

```
 # syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
 FROM node:10.15.3

 # Update and install any dependencies.
 RUN apt-get update
 RUN apt-get -y install openssh-client git

 # Clone the private repository
 RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@github.com:<USER>/<PRIVATE_REPO>.git
```

I have already added my ssh key using `ssh-add` and it is listed successfully when running `ssh-add -L`.

To build the container I then use the following command:

```
docker build --ssh default .
```

I am still getting the following error message when trying to build the image:

> Host key verification failed.

The docker client I am using is running macOS Mojave.

Comment: While I do not have an answer to your question, note that *"host key"* is not the same thing as your *"ssh key"*. See my article about [SSH Key Pairs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys) to understand the difference. It may get you on the right track.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - Aah this might be the problem. I actually might have to add an entry in to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` for this to work?

Comment: Yes, that may work. It would definitely work with plain `ssh`. I do not know about Docker.

Comment: Oh my god I am so stupid. I actually had a section which added github.com to the `known_hosts` file, the reason it did *not* work was because I had misspelled the filename e.g `RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 /root/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/know_hosts`. Thank you for helping me out =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the above comments the `host key` is not the same thing as the `ssh key` and the reason why this did not work was not related to my forwarded ssh key, instead I needed to add the host into `~/.ssh/known_hosts`:

```
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 /root/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```